# Mule ESB JAXB XML To Object Transformer Better Way?

Tags: jaxb, esb, mule, transformer-model

Mule 3.3 can automatically unmarshall an XML string to an object using JAXB given that:
    1. you first register your jaxb annotated classes with spring.
    2. there is a component that requires such type as input

So I have managed to do the transformation, but I had to create a "DumbTransformer" that does nothing.  It has a method that returns the same object it receives.  I need it in order to trigger the XML to Object conversion so that I can further process the message.

Flow Example:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="dumbTransformer" class="foo.bar.DumbTransformer"/>
</spring:beans>

<flow name="main" doc:name="main">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="in" doc:name="VM" />
        <component doc:name="Java">
            <spring-object bean="dumbTransformer"/>
        </component>
        <splitter expression="#[payload.items]" doc:name="Split Items"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Item"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="out" doc:name="VM" />
</flow>
```

DumbTransformer.java

```
package foo.bar;

@ContainsTransformerMethods
public class InvoiceUnmarshaller extends AbstractTransformer {

    @Transformer
    public MyJaxbAnnotatedClass foo(@Payload MyJaxbAnnotatedClass i) {
        return i;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to acomplish this without having to create such DumbTransformers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed it, the JAXB deserialization doesn't occur because there is no component to satisfy:

> 1. there is a component that requires such type as input

So what if you had an auto-transformer to do just that:

```
<auto-transformer returnClass="foo.bar.MyJaxbAnnotatedClass" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Mule XML Module](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/XML+Module+Reference) provides OOTB a [JAXB Transformer](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/JAXB+Transformers). I would rather leverage mule capabilities whenever possible rather than writing custom code

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I found your answer to vague.